# The browser platform is not supported by cordova-plugin-mfp. No operation will be performed for the specified platform

Tags: cordova, browser, mfp

I am trying to add cordova browser platform to my ionic project. But I get this error. Can someone explain me why ?

The browser platform is not supported by cordova-plugin-mfp. No operation will be performed for the specified platform.

Comment: Can someone help me with this error message!!

Comment: i dont think its an error. Did the platform got added?

Comment: The platform is added and i get this error when i run the command - cordova run browser. FYI
cordova platform ls     gave me
 android 6.2.3
 browser 5.0.1
 ios 4.4.0

Comment: tried it on my setup and it working fine. The cordova version is 7.0.1. I dint tried with Ionic but with barebone cordova project. Browser platform version is 4.1.0 So its something to do with your setup or Ionic

Comment: @Gandhi I tried to create a cordova project and tried to add - cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp. But looks like the plugin is not added successfully.Got the below error message 
cp: dest file no such file or directory: C:\SampleWeb\trialapp\platforms\browser\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-mfp\worklight\analytics

and many more similar errors related to express, request.

Comment: did you tried this on ionic project or barebone cordova project?

Answer (score 0):

The platform was probably added, you just saw this warning because this plugin doesn't work with the browser platform.
By the way, it's latest version does support browser platform:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mfp

Maybe consider upgrading to a newer version?

Comment: I have added the browser platform and the version is 5.0.1
I think this is the latest version

Comment: cordova plugin ls listed me cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017072706 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation" which means the plugin is added

Comment: So you are running a current version, have you checked to see if the browser platform was added despite of the warning? What happens if you run 'ionic cordova run browser' ?

Comment: Although I get this warning, I am able to run the application in browser which means ionic cordova run browser is working . So my assumption is that its just a warning and doesnt harm anything.

Answer (score 0):

MFP 8 version doesn't support Browser version except in stub mode (Dummy One) Till MFP 7.1 version is supported over browser.

for more information : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/wl_welcome.html